# Kernel, Loader, and Firmware boot times too high, how can I speed up them?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have a problem with boot times on my HDD.

```
systemd-analyze time
```

returns this:

```
Startup finished in 5.413s (firmware) + 6.303s (loader) + 4.379s (kernel) + 26.090s (userspace) = 42.187s
```

I managed to reduce the "userspace" using "critical-chain" and removing useless services. But I firmware, loader, and kernel times seems to be too high. I come from a clean installation of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and I'm using kernel 4.4.0-45-generic.

Can you help me?